# Chrome extension: как изменить куки?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookie, chrome-extension, activity-life-cycle

Привет!

Мне нужно как-то поменять куки для сайта, чтобы сервер получил не те куки которые были, а те которые я хочу.

Насколко я понимаю, это нужно делать в background.js

```
"background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
},
```

background.js:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toString();
chrome.cookies.set({
    "name": "test",
    "url": "https://account.chatoptimizer.com/",
    "value": n
}, function (cookie) {});
```

И такой вариант работает, но работает только когда я обновляю расширении, а не страницу. Как вызывать код из background.js во время загрузки страницы(как я понимаю нужно это делать до отправки заголовков)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете "поймать" ивент изменение таба и тогда вызывать свою функцию (background.js):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeData, tab) {
  if (changeData.status == 'complete') {

    /*Вызов вашей функции*/

  }
})
```